# Live tiles duration

Tags: live-tiles

Photos live tile stops updating after approx 30 seconds and Cortana's live tile stops updating after approx 25 seconds. I have to touch my screen to see them alive again. Is there a duration for live tiles?

Comment: It is most likely app specific. What is your screen time out duration?

Comment: Also, why does the duration matter?

Comment: Screen timeout is 5 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The live tile animations stop after 25 seconds of inactivity - this cuts down on battery usage, and doesn't appear to be configurable.